# How massive should a body be in order to significantly affect the passage of time?

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation

I have read that the effects of time dilation due to relative motion become noticeable after a speed of about 10% of the speed of light.
The Wikipedia article on time dilation says this:

> It is only when an object approaches speeds on the order of 30,000
> km/s (1/10 the speed of light) that time dilation becomes important.

On a similar note, beyond what mass does gravitational time dilation become noticeable?

Comment: When the gravitational potential starts being significant compared to the square of the speed of light.

Comment: Also, that’s a dumb statement from Wikipedia… the point at which time dilation becomes important depends on how precisely you’re measuring. 10 percent of the speed of light isn’t a hard cutoff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia's statement is wrong: relativistic effects happen at all speeds, they're just harder to measure at slower speeds. In fact Chu et al at NIST have measured time dilation at relative speeds of 10 m/s.

Similarly gravitational time dilation always happens, and when it becomes "noticeable" depends on how good your clock is. For many purposes this would probably mean planet size bodies, but state of the att clocks are very very good and could no doubt observe effects on much smaller objects like asteroids. For example the NIST clock mentioned above should be able to detect gravitational time dilation due to a body with escape velocity on the order of 10 m/s, which corresponds to a smallish sized asteroid or moon (e.g. like Phobos).

Answer (score 4):

The real answer is "it depends on how precise you want your measurements to be". For example, GNSS satellites apply a correction for both speed-related time dilation due to them moving relative to the Earth's surface and gravity-related time acceleration due to them being in a weaker gravitational field compared to the Earth's surface. For them, a correction to the tune of $10^{-6}$ is significant.